# ecryptfs-recover-private cannot find encrypted home folder

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs, luks

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on a `Crypto-LUKS` partition, and within that partition, there is an `ecryptfs` encrypted `/home` folder. My Ubuntu OS won't boot anymore for unknown reasons as stated yesterday. So I went and booted my computer from a Live CD of Ubuntu.

I can see the encrypted drive with a padlock symbol on it and when I click on it, it prompts me for the passphrase, I type it in and it unlocks the drive. After that, I went ahead and tried to run `ecryptfs-recover-private` on a Terminal to see if it can find the encrypted `/home` folder. But, after a while, it doesn't find the directory. Let's be clear here, I know the Login password, but have no idea what the recovery passphrase for `ecryptfs` is. Is there still a chance for me to recover the files?

Output of `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`

```
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied 
find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/kernel/debug’.
```

But I know that there is a private directory in `/mnt/home/<user name>/`, as I mounted the `crypto_LUKS` partition onto this directory using `udisksctl`, how did the program NOT find that? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: May I ask why you would want *double* encryption?

Comment: I think initially, I was thinking that some sensitive data (financial information) is stored there, so I might as well use 2 passphrases with identical length to encrypt that stuff.

Comment: I found the answer by trial and error: essentially, I needed to do `sudo chroot /mnt` then run `ecryptfs-recover-private`. I was then prompted for the Login password and successfully gained access...

Comment: Please post that in the answer section then :)